# Does Javascript have an enhanced for loop syntax similar to Java's

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator

I am wondering if JavaScript has an enhanced for loop syntax that allows you to iterate over arrays.  For example, in Java, you can simply do the following:

```
String[] array = "hello there my friend".split(" ");

for (String s : array){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output is:

```
hello
there
my
friend
```

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?  Or do I have to use `array.length` and use standard for loop syntax as below?

```
var array = "hello there my friend".split(" ");

for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    document.write(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

JavaScript has a `foreach`-style loop (`for (x in a)`), but it is extremely bad coding practice to use it on an `Array`. Basically, the `array.length` approach is correct. There is also a `a.forEach(fn)` method in newer JavaScripts you can use, but it is not guaranteed to be present in all browsers - and it's slower than the `array.length` way.

**EDIT 2017**: "We'll see how it goes", indeed. In most engines now, `.forEach()` is now as fast or faster than `for(;;)`, as long as the function is inline, i.e. `arr.forEach(function() { ... })` is fast, `foo = function() { ... }; arr.forEach(foo)` might not be. One might think that the two should be identical, but the first is easier for the compiler to optimise than the second.

**Belated EDIT 2020**: There is now `for (const item of iterable)`, which solves the downsides of using `for (item in iterable)`.

Comment: Those same newer javascripts actually treat array indices as first-class properties, making it less of a bad practice. (It's still dangerous if you're supporting older js engines of course, or if your Array inherits properties and you don't check for that. Rocket's answer below demonstrates this.)

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing - you have to promise never to extend an array or its prototype. Also, the order is not guaranteed. Also, counterintuitively, but completely logically once you know what's going on, the indices are string representations of numbers. Also, if you have unset elements, they won't be iterated over. `a = []; a[3] = 5; for (i in a) { console.log(i, typeof(i)); }` gives `3 string` only, a distinctly different result than the `array.length` method.

Comment: @Rocket's answer won't protect you from properties set on the object itself. `a = [1,2,3]; a.listIndices = function() { for (i in a) { if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) { console.log(i); } } }; a.listIndices()` will list `0; 1; 2; listIndices`.

Comment: @Amadan: Unset elements won't be iterated over in `forEach` either.

Comment: @Rocket: You are correct. Thankfully, it _will_ skip any nonnumeric indices like `listProperty` above.

Comment: Please avoid all of these potential issues, and just use an implementation that is designed for just this purpose:  `forEach` (mentioned at the end of this answer, with additionally details in my own answer.)

Comment: @ziesemer: It's not that simple. If I was going for performance, I would absolutely rather use `array.length` method (with cached value). http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/9

Comment: @Amadan - that's a great demonstration, thanks for the response.  Now, it'd be very interesting to see how much of this disparity is optimized away by further browser JavaScript improvements over the next few months and years.  :-)

Comment: In a way, yes. Ruby does it, by having blocks not being objects, nor functions, but rather just pieces of code. What I believe is slowing JS down is the fact that you have to invoke a function in each pass of the `forEach`. We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 13):

Using the latest versions of JavaScript available to most modern browsers, you can do this:

```
array.forEach(function(x){
  document.write(x);
});
```

Details are at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.  If you're worried that a browser may not have support for this, you can add it yourself, using a (hopefully minified) version of the implementation that they have listed under "Compatibility".

This is a bit outdated, but this is a minified compatibility version of `forEach` that I derived from Mozilla's page a few years ago:

```
if(!Array.prototype.forEach){Array.prototype.forEach=function(b){if(typeof b!="function"){throw new TypeError()}var a=this.length,d=arguments[1],c;for(c=0;c<a;c++){if(c in this){b.call(d,this[c],c,this)}}}};
```

I've never run into any issues with this, but the implementation on Mozilla's page has since been expanded with some additional checks and code to make it compatible with ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18.

I have a file called `common.js` that I use and include on all of my pages to include this, as well as all of the other "Array extras" that were introduced with JavaScript 1.6, as listed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6#Array_extras.  (I've been meaning to get this updated and published for public use.)

This may not be the fastest approach (see http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/15 for some specifics - thanks for the link, Amadan) - but there is something to be said for conciseness and maintainability, etc.  Additionally, it'll be very interesting to see how much of this disparity is optimized away by further JavaScript engine improvements over the next few months and years.  :-)

Answer (score 13):

In ES2015(ES6), you can use the `for-of` loop. It's supported in most browser with the exception of IE.

```
let array = [10, 20, 30];

for (let value of array) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

[See the Mozilla explanation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: Good concise and complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `for(s in array)`, but be careful, it's not the same as a `foreach`.

In this case `s` is the key (index), not the value.  You also need to use `hasOwnProperty` because `in` loops though the object's `prototype` also.

```
for(s in array){
    if(array.hasOwnProperty(s)){
        console.log(array[s]);
    }
}
```

EDIT: As @Amadan pointed out, `hasOwnProperty` *does* iterate properties when they're added like this: `array.test = function(){}`.  I suggest **not** using `for...in`.

EDIT2: If your using a modern web browser (anything that isn't IE < 9), you can use `Array.forEach`).  @ziesemer points out that [Mozilla has a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) for this if you need to support IE < 9.

```
array.forEach(function(s){
    console.log(s);
});
```

NOTE: Personally I use [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) for my JavaScript projects, and I use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$.each(array, function(i,s){
    console.log(s);
});
```

Comment: Why not just use `forEach`?  (See Amadan's or my answer.)  Even this approach can break if things are assigned directly to the array that aren't meant to be indexed - even if not through the prototype.

Comment: Not all browsers (well I think all but IE) support `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: Array indices as first-class properties of the array are a relatively new feature for Javascript, are they not? Do you know in what version this syntax was introduced?

Comment: @kojiro: I have no idea, thought they always were.  I've also been taught to always use `hasOwnProperty` when using `for...in`.

Comment: `forEach` is supported as of IE 9.  For older versions, the compatibility function linked to from my answer can be used to add support for it.

Comment: @ziesemer: Personally, I use jQuery, so I use `$.each`.

Comment: @Rocket Sure, Crockford advocates that, but what he doesn't tell you is that .hasOwnProperty is not a method of several core objects (window, document, HTMLElement, …) in older *jscript* and those objects can't be extended.

Comment: @kojiro: That's because IE's (IE < 9) `JScript` engine is junk.  `window.hasOwnProperty` works in Chrome and Firefox and IE9.

Comment: @Rocket you'll get no disagreement here, but I still have to support junk.

Comment: @kojiro Array indexes have been first-class properties at least since ES3. I don't have any idea if that was new or not at the time, since that's the earliest version I've really studied. So all browsers support `for...in` loops on arrays, but it's still not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There's the "forEach" method on the Array prototype in newer JavaScript engines. Some libraries extend the prototype themselves with a similar method.

Comment: For example: jQuery has `$.each`.

Comment: @Rocket yes, and Prototype adds ".each" to the Array prototype (or it used to, anyway), and things like Underscore and Functional also do similar things.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var errorList = new Array();
 errorList.push("e1");
 errorList.push("e2");
      
 for (var indx in errorList) {
     alert(errorList[indx]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1,2,3];
for (i in x) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: This will not work as expected.  In a `for...in` loop, `i` is the key (index), not the value.  You need to `console.log(x[i])`.  You should also check `if(x.hasOwnProperty(x))` to make sure you're not iterating over properties in the `prototype`.