# Javascript properties reflection

Tags: javascript, reflection, properties

First of all, let me warn you that i am not a javascript guru.
I already found a few questions regarding this topic but almost all of them answer with the same solution.
I have a simple custom javascript object:

```
var errorMsg ={
      msg1 : "x",
      msg2 : "y",
      msg3 : "z",
      msg4 : "t"
}
```

and i want to get all the properties names from the object like ["msg1","msg2","msg3","msg4"].
Like i told almost solution point to the use of the for/in loop to iterate over all properties name. But my app will run in IE6 and above, and i research that IE does not support this loop or at least the IE6. So what can i do ?
The last question is , where can i find a good javascript reference ? I saw that the Object have a method that returns keys like Object.keys() , where can i find a good reference that gives me all the properties and method related with javascript built in objects ?

Comment: MDN is the best resource for this sort of thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Where have you read that IE6 does not support `for...in`? Regarding the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: Also, IE6 is almost dead, help it die....  http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a generic method for returning an array of keys from any object,
and use the function's call method to operate on the errorMsg object:

```
var errorMsg={
    msg1:"x",
    msg2:"y",
    msg3:"z",
    msg4:"t"
}
function keyArray(){
    var A= [];
    for(var p in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(p)) A.push(p);
    }
    return A;
}
keyArray.call(errorMsg)

/*  returned value: (Array)
msg1,msg2,msg3,msg4
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

First, see [Does Javascript have an enhanced for loop syntax similar to Java's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681593/does-javascript-have-an-enhanced-for-loop-syntax-similar-to-javas) where we were just discussing this.  But since you are using an object instead of an Array here, not all of the answers will apply.  Here you will want to be sure that you're using a solution that involves `hasOwnProperty`.

In terms of a reference, I always use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference.  Everything that is listed there is of very high quality.  Just beware that not everything listed will apply equally to all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If for-in is no option, you could use an array containing *message objects*. You can use a standard for loop this way.

```
var errorMsg = [
      { name : "msg1", value : "x" },
      { name : "msg2", value : "y" },
      { name : "msg3", value : "z" },
      { name : "msg4", value : "t" }
];
```

You can't access the messages by name any more though - mapping message name to an index in `errorMsg` might be a workaround for this.